# Android Animation not stopping

Tags: android, animation

I have Animation in OnItemClickListener case. I want when I click on first button to play animation, when I click on 2nd button, to stop first animation and start second. But what happens:
When I start First animation on case 1, and click on case 2, start second animation. The case 1 animation is not stopping.
Here is my code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                        view.clearAnimation();
                    } else {
                        mp = MediaPlayer
                                .create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.case1sound);

                        mp.start();
                        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.scale_anim));
                    }

                    break;

                case 1:

                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                        view.clearAnimation();
                    } else {
                        mp = MediaPlayer
                                .create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.case2sound);

                        mp.start();
                        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.case1));
                    }

                    break;
```

And my anim XML file

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50.0%"
        android:pivotY="50.0%"
        android:repeatCount="3"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toXScale="0.90"
        android:toYScale="0.90" />


</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work. You want to stop the first and then start the second, but your code will only do 1 of them, not both

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is not what you want it to do.

Further more, you will need to keep track of the latest animation being played. So you can check that when case 2(which I presumed is `case 1:`) is clicked, do you need to restart case 2 or not.

Here are some possible scenarios:

1. Click Case 1 -> (Play animation 1) -> Click Case 2 -> (Stop animation 1) -> (Play animation 2)
2. Click Case 2 -> (Play animation 2) -> Click Case 2 -> (Stop animation 2)

If you don't mind animation 2 being played every time you click on Case 2 then you only need to think about your if condition.